# It's possible change the speedometer from mph to km/h?

Tags: midnight-club-los-angeles

In Midnight club 3 Los Angeles (ps3, complete edition). It's possible change the speedometer from mph to km/h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no such option. [There](http://board.gulli.com/thread/1329361-bei-midnight-club-los-angeles-von-mph-auf-km-h-umstellen-/) [are](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-13333-11147-1-0-1-0-comment-passer-en-km-h.htm) [several](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/939534-midnight-club-los-angeles/47338299) [people](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/939535-midnight-club-los-angeles/47079853) around the world who have the same problem. Probably it is because they use miles in Los Angeles...

Comment: Thanks. It is a pity that there is no such option. I'm from Brazil, here we use kilometers per hour. I'll have to mentally multiply by 1.6 every time when I want know my speed. :(

Comment: Yep. I included answers from France and Germany (at least it was in those languages, I suppose they live there then...) so you are not the only one.